# C# async dispatcher operation not recognising variable has changed since it started

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, dispatcher

I'm trying to implement a method which will trigger a UI event in WPF when the user places the mouse cursor into a component.

The behaviour should be:

1) The mouse cursor enters the component, calling the method `mouseEnter`

2) a 1 second timer starts

3) If the cursor is still in the component, trigger the event (in this case, opening an expander).

Initially, this was done using a `Thread`, but this is now carried out using asynchronously using the `Dispatcher`.

When the cursor enters the component, a `bool` named `mouseIn` is set to true.
When the cursor leaves the component, `mouseIn` is set to false.

The problem is that if the user places the cursor into the component, then moves it out of the component before the 1 second timer has elapsed, the `delegate` still sees `mouseIn` as true, even though I have confirmed that it is being set to false as soon as the cursor leaves it.

```
void mouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    mouseIn = true;
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        if (mouseIn) {
            exp.IsExpanded = true;
        }
    }
}

void mouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    mouseIn = false;
}
```

Does an `async delegate` normally only hold the state of the external variable at the point it was started?
If so, is there a way to force it to re-check the value, or failing that, a better way to implement this behaviour?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you schedule your `Action` on the UI thread and then block on it (although you do asynchronously queue it using `BeginInvoke`) using `Thread.Sleep` gives little chance for `mouseLeave` event handler to be invoked.

You can have a solution without block the message loop at all using `Task.Delay`. It will yield control back to the UI message loop once hitting the `await`, and the continuation will be scheduled on the UI thread once the delay elapses:

```
async void mouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseIn = true;
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    if (mouseIn) 
    {
        exp.IsExpanded = true;
    }
}

void mouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{
    mouseIn = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yuval, that was exactly what I needed!

Comment: this demonstrates perfectly why blocking calls are evil. be kind to your threads!

Answer (score 2):

There is only one copy of the `mouseIn` variable, the delegate is seeing the same variable.  The problem is that your `mouseLeave` event isn't being called because of the `Thread.Sleep(1000)` call in your delegate.

`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` will invoke your action back on the UI thread.  You then block the UI thread for 1 second with the `Thread.Sleep` call.  When the UI thread is sleeping it does not respond to user input so the mouse move won't have registered.  Instead of `Thread.Sleep` use `async/await` with `Task.Delay` which will not block the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks shf301, that does pretty succinctly explain the problem. It seems so obvious now, but I've been working on this for some time and I just didn't spot the cause.